# Horizontal Scrolling GridView

Tags: android, gridview, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to create a Horizontal Scrollable GridView of my own (don't want to use anything that is out there because I want to play with the concept and understand it better on my own) but for some reason no grid item appears on screen.

The GridLayout is part of a ListItem and I instantiate it there. (if i use a normal GridLayout, that is not added in a Scroll View the data will show)

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

        <GridView
           android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
         />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And Here is my adapter Class:

```
public class RelatedCarsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Cars> cars;

public RelatedCarsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList< Cars > cars) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.cars = cars;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cars.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return cars.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    TextView dummyTextView = new TextView(mContext);
    dummyTextView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    return dummyTextView;
    }
}
```

And this is how I instantiate it :

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            RelatedCarsAdapter relatedCarsAdapter = new RelatedCarsAdapter(mContext, cars);
            gridView.setNumColumns(cars.size());
            gridView.setAdapter(relatedCarsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView won't scroll inside HorizontalScrollView. You need to use RecyclerView instead of GridView in your layout (and probably extend RecyclerView.Adapter)

See documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html